# Is there a way to process CSS using Vite and then return the processed CSS to Laravel for embedding?

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, vite

Okay, basically, I'm producing HTML reports that can be emailed, downloaded or embedded and so using a link tag isn't optimal.  But I need to able to run everything through PostCSS and fix the image links and such, so I want to know if there's a way in Laravel to ask Vite to process the CSS and then return the result either as a full string or as a file path (so I can use file_get_contents), so I can embed it directly in the page head.

Comment: missed the npm run build cmd?

Comment: No, I'm asking if there's a way to get the equivalent of the run build command in PHP so I can embed it directly rather than as a link, because I can't be sure the link will remain the same.